# How can we post XML strings along with text strings in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, post

```
NSString *starcardstr=@"https://starcardsindia.com/test/api/UserAuthentication";
//NSString *poststr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://starcardsindia.com/api/OTPverification"];
                   //  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:poststr];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:starcardstr];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:starcardstr]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"post"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/xml"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *pbody=[NSMutableData data];
[pbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<xml>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// create a post

[pbody appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//[pbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Starcard>                                                  <mobie_no>9959571336</mobie_no><Password>1234</Password><date>2015-03-31</date><imei_no>1234</imei_no></Starcard>"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//[request setHTTPBody:pbody];
[pbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Starcard><mobileno>9959571336</mobileno><date>2015</date><imei_no>123456</imei_no></Starcard>"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:pbody];`
```

String xmlString = "" + "" + Mobile + "" + "" + Password + "" + "" + Imei_NO + "" + "" + formattedDate + "" + ""; –  user3656396`

Comment: String xmlString = "<starcard>" + "<mobile_no>" + Mobile
      + "</mobile_no>" + "<password>" + Password
      + "</password>" + "<imei_no>" + Imei_NO + "</imei_no>"
      + "<date>" + formattedDate + "</date>" + "</starcard>";

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking nor is it clear what the comment is. You need to provide more information about the problem you are having? You can edit your question, it is much better to add additional information to the question than add a comment.

Comment: we need to send the data like